# Serenity report doesn't show scenario details with Scenario Outline

Tags: cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I have created a cucumber scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: The one where we fetch classifications for a list of part numbers in batch from CCS
        Given the parts with classifications from CCS for plant XX
        When we lookup classifications for "KIC-OCS" plant IN/IT and classification region and type DE/IMPORT for effective date 06/23/2023 with derivations <derivationsEnabled> and the parts
       Then the classifications for the parts should be found  
         | Part Exists         |
         | <partExist>|
       Examples:
         | derivationsEnabled | partExist|
         | enabled            | true     |
         | disabled           | false    |
```

When I run it, it executes the scenario with both datasets and then in the generated serenity report it also shows two scenarios, but by clicking on the scenario to see the details (steps) I get to a dead link (file not found)

Am I missing something in the configuration?

Versions in gradle (7.4.2):

Plugin:
id 'net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin' version '2.4.34'

cucumberVersion = '7.12.1'
serenityVersion = '3.9.7'

The current view of the report:
[image: Before clicking to the scenario]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the test, there will be 2 scenarios.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).